# django admin returns 403 csrf error

Tags: python, angularjs, django, angular, authentication

I am producing a django/angular project. Django being the backend administration and Angular being the frontend/public display. I have created a Django 1.11 app and loaded all files, installed dependencies, etc. Locally, the site works fine and as expected. Also, since forms will be Angular js I commented out the `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in my settings.py which I thought would disable the csrf token even being needed, but apparently not.

After setting up server and installing files the admin login page appears but I get the following error when I try and login:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /admin/login/
```

Any ideas on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't commented out the 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in your settings.py, The CSRF middleware provides easy-to-use protection against Cross Site Request Forgeries. Since you are using Augualr js instead of django forms and views, you can set the csrftoken cookie in your browser cookies. Check this for detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#module-django.middleware.csrf

Comment: I did make the csrf middleware active but I am still getting the same error. Thanks for the link too